# Programming style from "Game Coding Complete"

Tags: c++

I have recently read Mike McShaffry's [Game Coding Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584506806) and noticed the code style I haven't seen elsewhere yet. The more important things I noticed were the names of base classes defining interfaces starting with an I like `IActor`, protected member variables' names starting with m_ like `m_Type` and names of virtual methods like `VSetId()`. To show a bigger, more readable example:

```
class BaseActor : public IActor 
{ 
    friend class BaseGameLogic;
protected: ActorId m_id; 
    Mat4×4 m_Mat; 
    int m_Type; 
    shared_ptr <ActorParams> m_Params; 
    virtual void VSetID(ActorId id) { m_id = id; } 
    virtual void VSetMat(const Mat4×4 &newMat) { m_Mat = newMat; } 
public: 
    BaseActor(Mat4×4 mat, int type, shared_ptr<ActorParams> params) 
        { m_Mat=mat; m_Type=type; m_Params=params; } 
    /* more code here */
};
```

I pretty much like this style: it seems justified and looks like it helps increase the overall readability of the code. **The question is:** Is it a more-or-less established standard? Is there any more to it than the things I mentioned?

Comment: This style really brings a bad name to Hungary. It should be renamed. <tongue-in-cheek />

Comment: The IForInterface form used heavily in both .NET (e.g. IDictionary) and COM+ (e.g. IDispatch). I suspect it serves a similar intent here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called Hungarian Notation. It's encoding information about the variable into the variable name.

For example, `m_params` means "a member variable called params". `IActor` means "A class called Actor intended to be used as an ifterface". It is something that is a very hot topic. Most people agree Hungarian Notation is a poor choice, but many will defend what they do as not Hungarian.

Comment: Reasonable Hungarian Notation is a good thing.  Most arguments against HN cited WIN32 and things like dwSize.  It is bad to encode a variable's type in its name (syntax).  It can improve a variable's name to encode its purpose (semantics).

Comment: @deft_code I have to disagree. There's is no information that any Hungarian notation can provide you that either a decent editor or an English word for a variable name cannot convey. All it does is obfuscate the purpose of the variable or cause longer issues with your auto complete. Ideally, it's purpose would be defined by it's type. If you need a new purpose for an existing type, it's behaviors should change as well, meaning it should be a different class.

Answer (score 1):

That looks very similar to [Hungarian Notation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) It depends on who you ask, but its a rather lets say "aged" style.

Answer (score 1):

All of that seems fairly common. I dont recognize anyone else using the V prep for virtual methods. But its more about making the code human followable then anything else. Sounds like a good use to me.

Most of the coding I do is in C# and they use the same conventions for the most part. tho it is uncommon to see m_ for the member variables. Thats more common to C/C++ tho I have seen the same convention used in C# or the variables would start with _ alone. which is also a common convention in Objective-C. Something to separate the Property from the Variable that the property uses as a container.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that, and I'm no game programmer.  The 'I' probably indicates that the class is intended to be an interface - all virtual methods and no data members.  Using m_ is quite common, but so are other conventions. I think I first saw m_ naming convention in some Microsoft Windows examples in the late 1980s but that's probably not its origin.  There are multiple coding standards around that follow these conventions (but differ in other ways) - I can't name any specific ones at the moment, but look around.

Answer (score 0):

The initial I to denote interfaces (and A for abstract classes) isn't such a bad practice, however the m_ prefix to denote member variables is horrid. I believe the reasoning behind it is that it allows the parameters to be named nicer by preventing shadowing of member variables. However you will mainly work with member variables in your class, and the m_ prefix really clutters code, hindering readability. It is much better to just rename the parameter, for example id -> pId, id_, identifier, id_p, p_id, etc.

The V to denote virtual methods might be useful if you somehow declared methods virtual in the parent class but not in the child class, and you desperately need to know whether it is virtual or not, however this is easily fixed by declaring them virtual in the child class as well. Otherwise I do not see any advantage.